# I can not get all the data

Tags: c#

I'm read the rows and using it is run sql query. Loop was correct but only one line is being processed. Please support me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Excel_read.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                string readRow = Excel_read.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                //MessageBox.Show(xaxa);

                //MessageBox.Show(readRow);

                MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `Calling number`,`Call time`  FROM test.tbltest WHERE `Calling number` = " + readRow + " GROUP BY `Calling number`", connection);

                System.Data.DataTable test = new System.Data.DataTable();
                adp.Fill(test);
                Excel_read.DataSource = test;
                adp.Dispose();
            }
            connection.Close();
```

Comment: Have you debugged this

Comment: Yes, only one line provided data.

Comment: Row indexes in Excel are from 1 to Excel_read.Rows.Count inclusively

Comment: Check if Excel_read.Rows.Count>1

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < Excel_read.Rows.Count - 1; i++) Did you say this ??

Comment: How many rows are actually in the excel sheet?

Comment: if (Excel_read.Rows.Count > 1)
            {} is the same as the previous result

Comment: What is `Excel_read`?

Comment: I'm sorry. This is dataGridView alias name.

Comment: put `Calling number`,`Call time` both in group by clause

Comment: You're looping over the rows in `Excel_read.Rows`, and within each loop you're changing `Excel_read.DataSource`. You're changing it while you're reading it. It's not clear why you're doing that. It's not going to have any effect because you're not calling `DataBind`, but if you do call `DataBind` bad things will happen because the rows will change as you're looping through them.

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem?